# Are Valgrind errors normal in Python import matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, valgrind

I create a empty py file only import matplotlib(3.5.2)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and use Valgrind with commond

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=definite --undef-value-errors=no python ./test_mem_leak.py
```

but get result as follows,it shows that definitely lost: 128 bytes in 2 blocks:

```
==30676== LEAK SUMMARY:
==30676==    definitely lost: 128 bytes in 2 blocks
==30676==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30676==      possibly lost: 289,343 bytes in 114 blocks
==30676==    still reachable: 2,702,454 bytes in 4,174 blocks
==30676==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30676== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==30676== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==30676== 
==30676== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==30676== ERROR SUMMARY: 13670 errors from 180 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

How to explain this ?

Comment: ==30676== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all